# How to avoid "TypeError: unhashable type" when Python Thrift decodes a map indexed by a struct

Tags: python, dictionary, thrift

The file model.thrift contains the following Thrift model:

```
struct Coordinate {
    1: required i32 x;
    2: required i32 y;
}

struct Terrain {
    1: required map<Coordinate, i32> altitude_samples;
}
```

Note that we have a map (altitude_samples) indexed by a struct (Coordinate).

I use the Thrift compiler to generate Python encoding and decoding classes:

```
thrift -gen py model.thrift
```

I use the following Python code to decode a Terrain object from a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
sys.path.append('gen-py')

import thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol
import thrift.transport.TTransport
import model.ttypes

def decode_terrain_from_file():
    file = open("terrain.dat", "rb")
    transport = thrift.transport.TTransport.TFileObjectTransport(file)
    protocol = thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    terrain = model.ttypes.Terrain()
    terrain.read(protocol)
    print(terrain)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    decode_terrain_from_file()
```

When I run this program, I get the following error:

```
(env) $ python py_decode.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_decode.py", line 19, in <module>
    decode_terrain_from_file()
  File "py_decode.py", line 15, in decode_terrain_from_file
    terrain.read(protocol)
  File "gen-py/model/ttypes.py", line 119, in read
    self.altitude_samples[_key5] = _val6
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Coordinate
```

Comment: Looks ilke https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Thrift compiler cannot automatically generate the hash function for the Coordinate class.

You must add the hash function manually as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
sys.path.append('gen-py')

import thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol
import thrift.transport.TTransport
import model.ttypes

model.ttypes.Coordinate.__hash__ = lambda self: hash((self.x, self.y))

def decode_terrain_from_file():
    file = open("terrain.dat", "rb")
    transport = thrift.transport.TTransport.TFileObjectTransport(file)
    protocol = thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    terrain = model.ttypes.Terrain()
    terrain.read(protocol)
    print(terrain)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    decode_terrain_from_file()
```

Note that a similar problem occurs for C++ generated code. In the C++ case you need to manually add the Coordinate::operator< to the program. Thrift does generate the declaration for the Coordinate::operator< but does not generate the implementation of Coordinate::operator<. Once again, the reason for this is that Thrift does not understand the semantics of the struct and hence cannot guess the correct implementation of the comparison operator.

```
bool Coordinate::operator<(const Coordinate& other) const
{
    if (x < other.x) {
        return true;
    } else if (x > other.x) {
        return false;
    } else if (y < other.y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does then require that your code treats `Coordinate` instances as immutable. They also need to have a `__eq__` method that'll compare two instances on the same two attributes.

Comment: And there are similar issues in Go: [Thrift go support of map with struct value as key](//stackoverflow.com/q/23180665)

Comment: Thanks! Just for my understanding: why do we need to treat them as immutable? And why is `__eq__` also needed (I did not add `__eq__` to my test program, and nothing appeared to be broken).

Comment: See [What happens if an object's \_\_hash\_\_ changes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/23161035) for what happens when an object stored in a dict is mutated. It could be that thrift does generate a suitable `__eq__` method already, but if not you can end up with two objects with the same attributes and the same hash, butt they both are stored in the hash as different keys because they don't test equal. By default equality between instances is determined by identity.